# Algebraic hypersurfaces and Coxeter groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coxeter-groups, hypersurfaces

What is the minimum degree of an algebraic hypersurface (not necessarily smooth) having each Coxeter group as its symmetry group?

Comment: Demanding smoothness, or not?

Comment: No, it doesn’t have to be smooth.

Comment: You need a degree-3 curve in the plane in order for the symmetry group to be $A_2$, but in type $B_2$ you can get away with taking only $2$ (orthogonal) hyperplanes.  That is, take one of the two $W$-orbits of reflecting hyperplanes.  Is it possible that in general the answer is the smallest size of a $W$-orbit of reflecting hyperplanes?  (Off the top of my head, I don't know either direction for answering that question—neither that a $W$-orbit of reflecting hyperplanes doesn't have a symmetry group larger than $W$, nor that this would minimize the degree.  But it seems worth asking.)

Comment: If a symmetry fixes each of the fundamental invariants, then it fixes the entire ring of invariants.  Thus, an upper bound on the minimum degree should be the least common multiple of the degrees of the fundamental invariants (just take a sufficiently general linear combination of powers of the fundamental invariants).